# Xquery for Converting CSV file to XML file

Tags: xml, rest, csv, xquery

I am working on the RESTful XRX as I have to create a restful crud operations on eXist database. I have some problem to create the Xquery which will convert given csv file into XML format. How can I create Xquery file for converting the given csv file into XML file format?

Answer (score 1):

I think you asked the same question on the exist-open mailing list, and you've received an answer there.  But for the benefit of others, let me include a link to the XQuery Wikibook article which was adapted from that answer:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Parsing_CSV

The approach in this article is clearly very specific to your data, but it could easily be extended to allow for more diverse types of CSV data.